# SSL Socket connect timeout

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, timeout, connection

How can I configure connect timeout for SSL Sockets in Java?

For plain sockets, I can simply create new socket instance without any target endpoint using `new Socket()`, and then call [connect(SocketAddress endpoint, int timeout)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)) method. With SSL sockets, I cannot create `new SSLSocket()` and `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket()` method with no endpoint throws `UnsupportedOperationException` with **Unconnected sockets not implemented** message.

Is there a way to use connect timeouts for SSL Sockets in Java, using standard java libs only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you could use your current approach of creating the `Socket` and then connecting it. To establish `SSL` over the connection you could use **[`SSLSocketFactory.createSocket`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.net.Socket,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean%29)**

> Returns a socket layered over an
>   existing socket connected to the named
>   host, at the given port.

This way you get full control over the connection and *then* you negociate setting up SSL on top of it. Please let me know if I misread your question.

Comment: Ah, that looks like an option. I will try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

With java 1.7 the following does not throw the exception stated in the question:

```java
String host = "example.com";
int port = 12345;
int connectTimeout = 5000;
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connectTimeout);
socket.startHandshake();
```

so it's business as usual.

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating on @predi's answer, I found that I needed to use "setSoTimeout" too. Otherwise sometimes it gets stuck in the handshake (on very unstable connections):

```
    final int connectTimeout = 30 * 1000;
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
    socket.setSoTimeout(connectTimeout);
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAddress, port), connectTimeout);
    socket.startHandshake();
    socket.setSoTimeout(0);`
```